# WPF How to expose fields on a UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a simple application with just a window and a user control. The user control has a list box. The user control is positioned on the Window and I want to bind the user control's listbox to an element on the window's data context.

The examples I've been able to find have CLR properties on the user control which are accessed in code not via XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2b.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication2b="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2b" Title="MainWindow" Height="410" Width="520">
<Grid>
    <WpfApplication2b:MyUserControl></WpfApplication2b:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

And here is the user control itself.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2b.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="#FFD8AA13">
    <ListBox Height="276" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" />
</Grid>
```

As you can see it's just a listbox on a different coloured background. I have no idea where to go next :)

I'm guessing that I need to add a code behind property for the list box as a dependency property?

Edit: I've added a dependencyProperty, but I don't think I've quite got the point.

```
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListBoxProperty;

    static MyUserControl()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata md = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata();
        MyUserControl.ListBoxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyListBox", typeof (ListBox),
                                                                    typeof (MyUserControl), md);

    }

    public ListBox MyListBox
    {
        get
        {
            return (ListBox) GetValue(ListBoxProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ListBoxProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserControl` will inherit the `DataContext` from the Window so you can bind properties on the `ListBox` as though it were declared in the Window. To make the control more flexible you can declare Dependency Properties for the data items from the `DataContext` that you want to use (i.e. an `ItemsSource` collection) and pass them *into* the control, rather than passing the `ListBox` *out*.

Comment: I'm doing something similar do what John is suggesting with regard to creating a new ItemsSource DependencyProperty on the UserControl or in my case a custom Control class but I've run into problems with bindings that use RelativeSource to FindAncestor on the items (MenuItem in my case). To me it almost seems that the binding is being resolved too early when it is declared on my outer collection for my control and even though the collection is bound to the ItemsSource of an inner ContextMenu control, the binding fails to find the ContextMenu element as an ancestor.

Comment: @jpierson - Your issue is probably caused by the fact that MenuItems and ToolTips exist in a separate Visual Tree so ElementName and RelativeSource FindAncestor Bindings don't work inside them.

Comment: Your probably right in most cases but I would still expect RelativeSource bindings to the ContextMenu itself to work which it will when the MenuItems are placed directly under a ContextMenu but when bound to a collection that itself is defined in XAML then it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question/answer is almost what you're looking for.  Essentially you're going to need to make a dependency property (using the `AddOwner` registration method) and set up the DataBinding on the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` to hook to the Dependency Property.  The example in the answer does the same thing for a `ComboBox`, and should be almost the same for a `ListBox`.

[Exposing inner Control properties for binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169090/exposing-inner-control-properties-for-binding-in-wpf)